# Shape equals ()

Tags: tensorflow

I am reading the tests in the [TensorFlow MNIST official model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/mnist_test.py). Line 49 has:

```
self.assertEqual(loss.shape, ())
```

and selected lines leading up to it are:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 100

def dummy_input_fn():
  image = tf.random_uniform([BATCH_SIZE, 784])
  labels = tf.random_uniform([BATCH_SIZE, 1], maxval=9, dtype=tf.int32)
  return image, labels

def make_estimator():
  return tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=mnist.model_fn, params={
          'data_format': 'channels_last'
      })


class Tests(tf.test.TestCase):
  """Run tests for MNIST model."""

  def test_mnist(self):
    classifier = make_estimator()
    classifier.train(input_fn=dummy_input_fn, steps=2)

    loss = eval_results['loss']
    self.assertEqual(loss.shape, ())
```

but the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) suggests that a shape is an array of numbers:

```
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
tf.shape(t)  # [2, 2, 3]
```

These two statements that print the shape of the object don't help much:

```
print(loss.shape)
# prints `()`
print(tf.shape(loss))
# prints `Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(0,), dtype=int32)`
```

What is the meaning of a `()` shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loss` is a NumPy object and not a TensorFlow object:

```
print(type(loss))
# prints <class 'numpy.float32'>
print(loss)
# prints 2.2745261
```

I assume that a shape of `()` in NumPy means a scalar, though I could not find a documentation for it. You can see the list of object attributes (fields and methods) with:

```
print(dir(loss))
# prints `['T', '__abs__', '__add__', '__and__',
# ... 'shape', 'size', 'sort', ... ]`
```